# Cocoa webview on retina machines

Tags: css, cocoa, uiwebview, webkit, font-face

I am having an application which displays my own webpage using cocoa webview. I have defined all font sizes in CSS pixels, but still the text on retina machines looks blurred. As I understand, CSS pixels should translate to sufficient device pixels on HiDPI machines but it seems this is not happening.

Did anyone else also face this issue? Is there something which I missed? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: More of a CSS issue. I guess you need to have `media-queries`. Can you show us the CSS styles which you have ?